# Vim ctrlp plug in loading all files in my computer instead of current directory

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I'm using MacVim with the [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plug in for a file finder. It's supposed to load files in just the current directory to the file buffer. For example, I used to be able to `cd` into a directory, and then type `mvim` at the command line. That would load all the files in the current directory and only that directory, which was awesome for, say, a Rails project. Then my file finds would only search in that directory.

Recently, though, when I type `mvim` in a certain directory, the vim file buffer is all the files on my computer, rather than in the current directory, so finding the exact `index.html.haml` I need is impossible.

The weird thing is that when I say `mvim .`, it only tells me the files and folders in the current directory, which I would expect. And when I type `:pwd`, it tells me that the path I'm in is the current directory (a Rails project). But when I type `,t` to find a file, it's all the files on my computer.

[Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/79751190@N05/8498981123/in/photostream) is a screenshot. I've `cd`ed into a Rails project and have typed `,t` to bring up the file navigator using the `ctrlp` plugin, and I typed `config.rb` which should only bring up that directory's `config.rb` file, but instead, it's all the `config.rb`'s on my system!

Comment: Same thing. Which is weird, because the command line says, `16 files to edit`, which would make sense in this Rails app, but it still loads all the files.

Comment: What do you mean by "loads"? `$ mvim` "loads" nothing: it should start MacVim with an empty buffer and the working directory set to where you launched it from. `$ mvim .` (with the dot) is supposed to show a listing of the files contained in the directory where you issued that command. Could you show us your `~/.vimrc` and list your plugins?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/thenickcox/5018844) is my `.vimrc` as a gist and [here](https://gist.github.com/thenickcox/5018854) are my plugins.

Comment: It is probably unrelated but I see both pathogen stuff and vundle stuff in your `~/.vimrc`, you might want to clean it up. When you say "loads", do you mean that those files are listed in netrw?

Comment: OK. Add this line to your `~/.vimrc`: `let g:netrw_keepdir = 0` and reload Vim.

Comment: Same thing. All the files on my computer. I did just realize I'm using the commandT plugin (I'm using a friend's `.vimrc`) and added that to my question. That's the file navigator I'm using. I imagine that affects the file results.

Comment: No, that's CtrlP, not Command-T. "Sadly", I'm not in front of my Mac ATM so I can't really help you further. The issue is relativel simple. `:CtrlP` is supposed to list the files in Vim's "working directory" which you can see with `:pwd`. If you issued `$ mvim .` from your project's directory, `:pwd` should print the path of your project. But it looks like it's `/Users/username` instead.

Comment: That's the weird part. `:pwd` gives me the root of the Rails project I `cd`ed into.

Comment: A bug in CtrlP? You should try its issue tracker on github.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went to the GitHub page for ctrlp to file an issue and came across [this](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/search?q=150) issue. The suggested fix for an issue was to turn off starting in the current directory as a default behavior, so I just explicitly added the default to `~/.vimrc`, which fixed it:

`let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0`

### EDIT

While adding that line to my `~/.vimrc` did indeed fix the problem, it didn't address the **root** cause of this issue. The creator of the `ctrlp` suggested that I had created a `git` repository in my home folder (which `ctrlp` was looking in), which I somehow had. So another, more root fix for this issue was to just remove the `.git` directory in my home folder:

`$ rm -r ~/.git`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP .'
```